# How to monitor the realtime logging data in other window and collecting the data for creating a graph

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm building up python 2.7 script which can monitor the realtime log data capturing by the other terminal window and want to get the data and process to create the graph by using a trigger like clicking the enter key.

I have totally no idea how to do the below.

1) how to monitor the other window?
2) how to collect the data from that window?

Thanks,
Tatsu

Comment: Write log output to a file. Use some process to read *that file*, not a terminal window.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.